# Override woocommerce template from parent theme

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a parent theme with 5 child theme, is it possible to override the woocommerce template files from the parent, and have child themes using it?

I tried to put the template in parent-theme/woocommerce/single-product.php but it doesn't work.

It works only if I use child-theme1/woocommerce/single-product.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, by default woocommerce load parent files too, but the parent theme value in the database where not updated. I simply needed to change theme then reactive the child to update the database

Solution related to [get_template_directory_uri() in child theme pointing at child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267091/get-template-directory-uri-in-child-theme-pointing-at-child-theme)